# Storing data in indexDB when application is in offline PWA service worker

Tags: angular, nosql, progressive-web-apps

I had created an angular application with PWA service worker, which works offline also.
But I had stucked at storing the data in indexDB when the application is working in offline and wanted to hit the API with the indexDB data when application is working in online.

Issue1 : Unable to store data in indexDB when application is running in offline.
Issue2 : When the application gets running in online, The data that has been stored in indexDB should be hit to the API and store in API.

1. Storing data into indexDB when application is offline
2. After application is online the indexDB data should hit API, and stored data in API.

Answer (score 0):

there are three main steps to be followed to archive this.

1st you need to create a database and object store in IndexedDB to store your data.

```
const request = indexedDB.open('myDatabase', 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
  const db = event.target.result;
  const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('myObjectStore', { keyPath: 'id' });
};
```

2nd :next you need store the data in IndexedDB that you just created using above code block ,(when goes to offline):

```
if (!navigator.onLine) {
  const db = await openDatabase();
  const transaction = db.transaction('myObjectStore', 'readwrite');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('myObjectStore');
  
  const data = { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' };
  objectStore.add(data);
}
```

3rd : next hit the api back when comes to online again and pass the data:

```
window.addEventListener('online', async () => {
  const db = await openDatabase();
  const transaction = db.transaction('myObjectStore', 'readonly');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('myObjectStore');
  
  //const data = await objectStore.getAll();
  
  // all the logic to send data to API ,for that probably you are going to 
  //use  angular HttpClient
 
});
```

let me know if any mistake or any.

there are three main steps to be followed to archive this.

1st you need to create a database and object store in IndexedDB to store your data.

```
const request = indexedDB.open('myDatabase', 1);

request.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
  const db = event.target.result;
  const objectStore = db.createObjectStore('myObjectStore', { keyPath: 'id' });
};
```

2nd :next you need store the data in IndexedDB that you just created using above code block ,(when goes to offline):

```
if (!navigator.onLine) {
  const db = await openDatabase();
  const transaction = db.transaction('myObjectStore', 'readwrite');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('myObjectStore');
  
  const data = { id: 1, name: 'John Doe' };
  objectStore.add(data);
}
```

3rd : next hit the api back when comes to online again and pass the data:

```
window.addEventListener('online', async () => {
  const db = await openDatabase();
  const transaction = db.transaction('myObjectStore', 'readonly');
  const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('myObjectStore');
  
  //const data = await objectStore.getAll();
  
  // all the logic to send data to API ,for that probably you are going to 
  //use  angular HttpClient
 
});
```

let me know if any mistake or any.

EDIT:

the following material i am using from the online article(which may or may not be as it is or with little bit of modification language )  [offline-data](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/offline-data) (so that in case of any unavailability of this material on the original post ,it will we save here) ,it uses [idb](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) ,which is just a wrapper for IndexedDB named Jake Archibald's idb library, which is a tiny, and if you wish to use the syntex Promise it will be easy for that case whoever it is not require to use IndexedDB, IndexedDB can be use solely .

Creating and opening a database:

To open a database:

> 1.Use the openDB function to create a new IndexedDB database called
> cookbook. Because IndexedDB databases are versioned, you need to
> increase the version number whenever you make changes to the
> database structure. The second parameter is the database version.
> In the example is set to 1.
>
> 2.An initialization object containing an upgrade()
> callback is passed to openDB(). The callback function is called when
> the database is installed for the first time or when it upgrades to
> a new version. This function is the only place where actions can
> happen. Actions might include creating new object stores (the
> structures IndexedDB uses to organize data), or indexes (that you'd
> like to search on). This is also where data migration should
> happen. Typically, the upgrade() function contains a switch
> statement without break statements to allow each step to happen in
> order, based on what the old version of the database is.

```
import { openDB } from 'idb';
    
    async function createDB() {
      // Using https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb
      const db = await openDB('cookbook', 1, {
        upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction) {
          // Switch over the oldVersion, *without breaks*, to allow the database to be incrementally upgraded.
        switch(oldVersion) {
         case 0:
           // Placeholder to execute when database is created (oldVersion is 0)
         case 1:
           // Create a store of objects
           const store = db.createObjectStore('recipes', {
             // The `id` property of the object will be the key, and be incremented automatically
               autoIncrement: true,
               keyPath: 'id'
           });
           // Create an index called `name` based on the `type` property of objects in the store
           store.createIndex('type', 'type');
         }
       }
      });
    }
```

Adding data:

IndexedDB uses transactions. Transactions group actions together, so they happen as a unit. They help ensure that the database is always in a consistent state. They're also critical, if you have multiple copies of your app running, for preventing simultaneous writing to the same data. To add data:

> 1.Start a transaction with the mode set to readwrite.

> 2.Get the object
> store, where you'll add data.

> 3.Call add() with the data you are saving.
> The method receives data in dictionary form (as key/value pairs)and
> adds it to the object store. The dictionary must be cloneable using
> Structured Cloning. If you wanted to update an existing object,
> you'd call the put() method instead.

```
async function addData() {   // Using //https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb
  const cookies = {
      name: "Chocolate chips cookies",
      type: "dessert"
        cook_time_minutes: 25
  };
  const tx = await db.transaction('recipes', 'readwrite');
  const store = tx.objectStore('recipes');
  store.add(cookies);
  await tx.done;
}
```

Retrieving data

> Here is how you get data from IndexedDB:
>
> 1.Start a transaction and specify the object store or stores, and optionally transaction type.
>
> 2.Call objectStore() from that transaction. Make sure you specify the object store name.
>
> 3.Call get() with the key you want to get. By default the store uses its key as an index.

```
async function getData() {  // Using https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb
  const tx = await db.transaction('recipes', 'readonly')
  const store = tx.objectStore('recipes');
// Because in our case the `id` is the key, we would
// have to know in advance the value of the id to
// retrieve the record
  const value = await store.get([id]);
}
```

The storage manager

> Knowing how to manage your PWA's storage is particularly important >to
> storing and streaming network responses correctly.
>
> Storage capacity is shared among all storage options, including >Cache
> Storage, IndexedDB, Web Storage, and even the service worker file >and
> its dependencies. However, the amount of storage available varies
> from browser to browser. You're not likely to run out; sites could store megabytes and even gigabytes of data on some browsers. Chrome,
> for instance, allows the browser to use up to 80% of the total disk
> space, and an individual origin can use up to 60% of the entire disk space. For browsers that support the Storage API, you can know how much storage is still available for your app, its quota, and its use.
> The following example uses the Storage API to get estimate quota and usage, then calculates the percentage used and remaining bytes. >Note
> that navigator.storage returns an instance of StorageManager. There
> is a separate Storage interface and it is easy to get them confused.

```
if (navigator.storage && navigator.storage.estimate) {
  const quota = await navigator.storage.estimate();
  // quota.usage  Number of bytes used.
  // quota.quota  Maximum number of bytes available.
  const percentageUsed = (quota.usage / quota.quota) * 100;
  console.log(`You've used ${percentageUsed}% of the available storage.`);
  const remaining = quota.quota - quota.usage;
  console.log(`You can write up to ${remaining} more bytes.`);
}
```

Comment: HI Rainy sidewalks,Thanks you for fast reply.Give me any proper Link i have did same steps.Still not stored Indexdb

Comment: i think it will we helpful to go through the edit.